# Updated to php7.2 zip unlimited creating files

Tags: php, laravel, zip

So i have the following code and migrated from centos to ubuntu. PHP 7.0 to PH 7.2. The following code automatically keep generating the .dat and .psw files. non stop. (Generated 200GB of files in 2 hours). I don't see any error in the following code, and it just mysteriously not working properly

```
public function syncPosData() {
    $req = new SyncPosDataRequest($this->request->all());
    $validator = $req->validator($this->request->all());

    $data = $req->mapInsertData();
    $service = new LicenseService([
        LicensingConstant::LICENSE_KEY => $data[LicensingConstant::LICENSE_KEY],
        LicensingConstant::LICENSE_PASSWORD => $data[LicensingConstant::LICENSE_PASSWORD],
    ]);
    $license = $service->query();
    if ($license->isEmpty()) {
        return $this->invalidLoginException();
    }
    $companyService = new CompanyService();
    $company = $companyService->findByPk($license->first()->company_id);
    self::$json["data"] = $this->getPosData($company->first()->hash_id);

    return $this->render(true);
}

public function getPosData($id) {
    $directoryName = storage_path() . "/exports/";
    if (!is_dir($directoryName)) {
        mkdir($directoryName, 0755);
    }
    $directoryName = storage_path() . "/exports/" . $this->request['company_id'];
    if (!is_dir($directoryName)) {
        mkdir($directoryName, 0755);
    }
    $directoryName = $directoryName . "/psw/";
    if (!is_dir($directoryName)) {
        mkdir($directoryName, 0755);
    }
    $service = new CompanyService();
    $record = $service->findByHash($id);
    if ($record->isEmpty()) {
        return $this->invalidInputException();
    }
    $company_id = $record->first()->parentId;
    $psw_file_name = $record->first()->id ."_RVC_DATA_EXPORT_" . $this->clean($company_name) . "_" . date('Ymd_His') . ".psw";


    $fileImportExportService = new FileImportExportService([
        "file_name" => $psw_file_name,
        "file_path" => $directoryName . $psw_file_name,
        "company_id" => $company_id,
        "dealer" => $record->first()->id,
        "action" => "EXPORT",
        "created_by" => (empty($this->request->user_id)) ? "0" : $this->request->user_id,
    ]);
    $fileImportExportService->createWithHash();

    $this->zipFile = Zip::create($psw_file_name);
    $file_name = $directoryName . "RVC_DATA_EXPORT_" . date('Ymd_His') . ".dat";
    File::put($file_name, base64_encode(json_encode($excel)));
    $this->zipFile->add($file_name);
    $this->zipFile->close();
    return $psw_file_name; //base64_encode(json_encode($excel));
}
```

Comment: Does script working fine? did you see the php/apache error logs it's clean?

Comment: There's nothing in the code you've posted that suggests that it should create multiple files. But since we don't know how this code is called, or what those services you're using or what many of the functions you're calling actually does, we can't possibly know what's going on.

Comment: @VikashPathak No error

Comment: @MagnusEriksson True, I'm not the first hand developer. Hence why i wonder what cause the repeat generation of zip file too.

Comment: We can't help you debug your issue if we can't see the rest of the code. That's like expecting a doctor to sort out your aching foot while only letting them look at your hands.